# Просьба проверить UML sequence diagram

Tags: uml

Здравствуйте, задание было поставлено так:

"Нарисуйте UML диаграмму последовательности для прецедента регистрации в web системе. Регистрация должна включать в себя валидацию полей и верификацию пользовательского email. Так же добавьте в диаграмму выполнение одного действия, которое доступно только для авторизированных пользователей, например, получение своего профиля из системы."

Какие возможные ошибки я мог допустить при создании схемы или с ней все в порядке? Вот мой вариант схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну смотрите,

1) `Input username, login, email` оно же все еще в форму вносится, а не на веб сервер сразу.

2) Затем 2.1.2, 2.1.3 - Если ошибка, то это уже альтернативный путь, а у вас процесс продолжается как ни в чем ни бывало.Достаточно сделать сноску, что в случае ошибки переход к схеме такой-то.

3) С какого перепугу вы выделили два актора, когда там только один `User`? Registered - это всего лишь состояние.

4) Дальше. `Show Login Result` и сразу после него `getAccountData`. А если `login failed`, откуда там `AccountData` возьмется?

и т.д. Не зачет в общем